# Using simmer R on censored data to model time-to-events using a DES approach

Tags: r

I am looking to simulate time to events from censored patient data using a Discrete Event Simulation (DES) approach.
Has anyone tried to combine the use of simmer with survival modelling R packages such as flexsurv?
If so, what is your experience?

This would allow me to simulate time to events from time distributions including covariates, which is necessary for my project.
Thank you!

I have read the documentation and tutorials on the simmer R package and have tried to evaluate the possibility of including time distributions modelled using survival models.
As I have no experience with simmer, I have not yet tried to implement it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already read the vignettes, you see that the simulator is pretty flexible in this regard. Basically, you need to define your arrival processes and your time-to-event processes as functions that return one random number per call. In the vignettes, this is typically showcased by just defining some simple Poisson process with some `lambda` like `function() rexp(1, lambda)`. But you can complicate this as much as you need, including returning real data or the output from some model. Then these functions must be fed to `add_generator()` (for the case of arrival processes) and `timeout()` activities (for the case of time-to-event processes).

Apart from the docs, [here](https://r-simmer.org/slides/20230701_workshop.html#19) you have some resources about healthcare applications.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I suppose that what I could do to simulate time to events for multiple competing events including patient covariates,  is chose a function simulating time-to-event data such as 'sim.survdata'  and use it in the 'timeout()' function directly.
Thank you for the shared resources, however I have not found for the moment any material trying to mix DES with time to event data simulated from survival models (such as cox models).

Comment: I don't know of any resources mixing this, no. But conceptually it's the same idea, so it should be straighforward. In the case of `sim.survdata`, this generates a data frame.You can take a look at `add_dataframe` and `timeout_from_attribute`.